# Can you trade in Darkspore?

Tags: darkspore

Is there a way to trade items with my friends in Darkspore? I can't seem to figure it out, yet I would think in a multiplayer game you should be able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real trade function in Darkspore. It has been [suggested](http://forums.darkspore.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=468) and [discussed](http://forums.darkspore.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=8432), but never implemented.

The only way to "trade" with other players is by dropping recently aquired items on the ground, which limits it to items dropped in the current multiplayer game.